# How to render a html code input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating an Reactjs App that gets input in a text area. I want it to render the code if there is any html markup and show in another **div** block and bold or italic the text as it is done here in stackoverflow's text editor *like* or **mkd**.. 
Here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
              super(props);
              this.state={markdown:''};
              this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }
      handleChange(event){
             this.setState({markdown:event.target.value});
      }
      render(){
             return(<div className="main">
                    <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} type="text"/>
                    <div className="textShow">{this.state.markdown}</div>
                    </div>
             )
      }
}
```

What improvements should I make to it to render html markup and add other functionalities I have mentioned?

Comment: Do you want to render the markdown, or render the code you write in a syntax highlighting block? or both, like when you write in your text area for example : ``` **my Code is: ** `console.log('hello');`  ``` it will be rendered to a bold text with a syntax highlighted console.log for that use `marked` package with `hilight.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML like in this tip: https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

```
class Application extends React.Component {
     constructor(props){
              super(props);
              this.state={markdown:''};
              this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }
      handleChange(event){
             this.setState({markdown:event.target.value});
      }
      render(){
             return(<div className="main">
                    <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} type="text"/>
                     <div className="textShow" 
                       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.markdown}} />

                    </div>
             )
      }
}
```

Comment: add <b>My text</b> inside text area

Answer (score 2):

This tool does what you need, it can be used to display a text editor or render text from markdown or html

https://draftjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

Insert raw HTML using dangerouslySetInnerHTML as a last resort only.

According to the docs, ["This is mainly for cooperating with DOM string manipulation libraries"](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/special-non-dom-attributes.html). When you use it, you're giving up the benefit of React's DOM management.

I would use npm module `html-to-react`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react